# How to turn off all event notification under CentOS 6/GNOME?

Tags: centos

In the top right corner under CentOS 6/GNOME it pops up messages if ex.: ethernet is connected, update has failed, etc. How can I completely turn OFF these messages??

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds if it you're talking about the tooltips. This command should disable them from appearing:

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/panel/global/tooltips_enabled --type bool false
```

Comment: ty, i will try it out